# What is the fastest way to draw an array of lines?

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, overlay, draw

I need to draw an array of lines in overlay. Currently, I use canvas and bitmap and draw about 500 lines. The drawing time is very high - around 200 ms which is bad, but acceptable.

Now I need to add 500 lines more and the time grows significantly. What is the fastest way to do this? Do I need to use OpenGL? and How? What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Turning off anti-aliasing will speed things up a lot.  Be sure to profile your code to make sure rendering is the place where the time is actually going.  Once you have optimized things and the majority of time is spent in rendering and you have made the rendering as simple as possible, the next step you'll have to take is to move to OpenGL.

Comment: I can not remove the AA because the lines are getting ugly. may be i need to take the next step :(